# Unable to load the requested class: message in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter message library.

In my controller I have the following code

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('message');  
}

public function box($box_id=null, $language_name=null) {
   if($id_from_url[5]==null){
      $this->message->set('Please provide Box ID in URL.', 'error');
    }
}
```

In my view I use

```
    $this->message->display();
```

I have already put Message.php in my application/libraries folder
but I am getting the following error

```
Message: Missing argument 1 for CI_Message::CI_Message(), called in W:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\mediabox\system\core\Loader.php on line 1099 and defined
```

Any idea about this error ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think we are missing an important bit of the code here.

Comment: If it is this message library (http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Message) then make sure the library class has a __construct function (as all classes should have as per CI2)

Comment: @Rooneyl I didnt get your answer

Comment: yes I am using exactly this library

Comment: and what should be included in that __construct function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title is completely different than the error you are getting here. It clearly states that the Message library requires a parameter passed to its construct, but you are loading the library without any construct parameters.

You need to pass the construct parameters using the second parameter while loading it

```
$this->load->library('message',$config);
```

If you are actually talking about this Message library here http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Message then I must say, the documentation there is incomplete.

```
function CI_Message($config){    
    $this->CI =& get_instance();        
    $this->CI->load->library('session');

    if($this->CI->session->flashdata('_messages')) $this->messages = $this->CI->session->flashdata('_messages');
    if(isset($config['wrapper'])) $this->wrapper = $config['wrapper'];
}
```

The construct here requires a parameter `$config` passed to it.

Check the documentation thoroughly. You need to pass this while loading it.

```
$config = array();
$config['wrapper'] = array('<div id="messages">', '</div>');
```

then

```
$this->load->library('message',$config);
```

Comment: It says undefined variable $config

Comment: I have updated my code above.. you need to initialize `$config` first

Comment: should I initialize my config array and config[wrapper] in controller or the Message class ?

Comment: In your controller, before loading the message library

Comment: Now its giving internal server error 500 when the if condition is encountered

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9950/discussion-between-broncha-and-faryal-khan)